# how to I get the row content results from a Mysqli result

Tags: php, mysqli

I have

```
    $result = mysqli_query(...);
```

I know how to get the number rows, but I need the actual content. In regular mysql it like this:

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){...}
```

how do I do this with Mysqli?

Comment: @sebi: What do you mean by "doesn't work".

Comment: With While loop, code returns: unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: Post your code you have a syntax error.

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT over_Pics.Pic.PicID FROM over_Pics.Pic LEFT JOIN over_SeenPics.Seen ON over_Pics.Pic.PicID=over_SeenPics.Seen.PicID WHERE over_SeenPics.Seen.PicID IS NULL");

    if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
    echo "Your Pic ID: $row['PicID']"; 
    }

Comment: You need to use {$row['PicID']} to put array value in string

Comment: @KSiimson, Thank you, I wish could mark your answer as correct!